# Can we use different Java web frameworks in one web application?

Tags: java, jsf, spring-mvc, vaadin, web-frameworks

lets think we have a vaadin or gwt application. We want to develop some pages of this application in an another framework(for example spring mvc or jsf or wicket, etc...).

Is there a design pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: All those are built on top of the Servlet API, so they can interoperate using request or session attributes and context.

Comment: Servlets make your life easy :)

Comment: Even you can use other languages with java web frameworks like PHP.

Comment: it makes your application to complex, and maybe some conflicts too, while JSF, Spring,  ... are very cool and strong, but I prefer pure Servlet, it's perfect.

Comment: Just curios why you would want to mix several frameworks? What is the use case?

Comment: @Sergey by this platform i can develop my pages easier. Because some pages can be easily developed with X framework while it can be hard with another Y framework.

Comment: May be true in general, but I would avoid mix of Vaadin and JSF just because they have different paradigms. Vaadin is more "desktop oriented" and works like desktop application, while JSF app is split to pages (hence more "web oriented"). Combining of these 2 would be tricky and IMO application will be harder to maintain - even consitent look&feel will be a problem and you will have a lot of pain trying to make CSS same.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, you can use multiple frameworks in same web application.

What you have to do is, **create correct servlets and servlet-mappings in your web.xml file**. There may be some additional configurations you have to do which are framework specific.

For example, in case of wicket application you have to create wicket filter with your application class name as a parameter, for spring mvc you have to create a dispatcher servlet etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use different pattern, servlet can help you to do this, for example you can pass a param and according to his param you can do different things, for example:

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String type_frame= request.getParameter("framework");

              if (framework.equals("extjs")==true)
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher ("/jsp/PantallasGestion/tablaCajas.jsp");
              else
            {
         RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("xhtml if you uses primefaces... etc...");

            }

    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```